# ORA-12537 Error while implementing Hangfire.FluentNHibernate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, fluent-nhibernate, hangfire

I am implementing Hangfire.FluentNHibernate on .Net Framework 4.6 , the Oracle version is 11 with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v12.

I am getting ORA-12537 error while calling backgroundJob in my Controller like this:

BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => Debug.WriteLine("test"));

Here is my owin startup class:

```
 public class Startup
 {
     public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
     {
          var options = new FluentNHibernateStorageOptions
          {
              TransactionIsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable,
              QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
              JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
              CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
              UpdateSchema = true,
              DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
              InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
              TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
              DefaultSchema = "xxx", // use database provider's default schema
              TablePrefix = "Hangfire_" 
           }
          var connString 
             =System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Oracle"].ConnectionString;
          var storage = FluentNHibernateStorageFactory.For(ProviderTypeEnum.OracleClient10Managed, connString, options);
          GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(storage);
          app.UseHangfireDashboard();
   }}
```

It was able to create all tables and the sequence:

HANGFIRE_AGGREGATEDCOUNTER, HANGFIRE_COUNTER, HANGFIRE_DISTRIBUTEDLOCK, HANGFIRE_DUAL, HANGFIRE_HASH, HANGFIRE_JOB, HANGFIRE_JOBPARAMETER, HANGFIRE_JOBQUEUE, HANGFIRE_JOBSTATE, HANGFIRE_LIST, HANGFIRE_SERVER, HANGFIRE_SET, HIBERNATE_SEQUENCE

The code below throw an error says:

Background job creation failed. See the inner exception for details.

The inner exception says:

***could not insert: [Hangfire.FluentNHibernateStorage.Entities._Job][SQL: INSERT INTO HANGFIRE.Hangfire_Job (\"Id\", \"LastStateChangedAt\", \"StateData\", \"InvocationData\", \"Arguments\", \"CreatedAt\", \"ExpireAt\", \"StateName\", \"StateReason\") VALUES (HANGFIRE.hibernate_sequence.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) returning \"Id\" into :nhIdOutParam]***

the inner exception of this says:

***ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file***

Thank you very much in advance.